# HTML5 using <video> tag to insert every .mp4 from a directory

Tags: html, image, video

I'm trying to make a very basic image/video sharing website. To make things easier on myself, I was wondering if it was possible to mass-include ALL .mp4's from a directory instead of individually adding them. Here is my current doc:

```
<html>
<body>Under construction.<br>
<video autoplay>
<source src="away.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to have to manually add a `<video>` tag for every file, is there a way to add them all at once? Or something like YouTube does, where it shows a thumbnail but opens another page to play it. If there is a way to add the video sources en masse, does it include newly added files?

Comment: That would be a potential security concern that would allow a client side application to scrape whole directories of files, so I don't really think it's possible with just HTML.  If you're using a server scripting language like PHP, ASP.NET, JavaScript (Node), etc.  it would be easy to do there.  You would have to us the server-side language to find the images and then loop through them to create the HTML nodes to be served up to the end user client.

Comment: Would PHP be the way to go for a lot of files with varying sizes? Would file types affect this?

Comment: With PHP you can build a list of links to videos relatively easily. It might be the way to go if you already have it running on your server.

Comment: Generally the more popular server-side languages will be able to read the file system.  The choice of language at that point comes down to what you're most familiar with.  If you have any experience with any of those languages I would pick that.

Comment: ^both of you were a great help! I've never really used PHP because it seemed pretty scary to me compared to HTML, but I found a nice tutorial and I found a way to incorporate it into my idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
<?php
$dir    = './videos';
$video_files = [];

foreach(glob($dir.'/*.*') as $file) {
    $file_parts = pathinfo($file);
    if ($file_parts['extension'] == "mp4"){
        $video_files[] = $file;
    }
}

foreach($video_files as $video_file) {
    echo "<video autoplay>";
    echo "<source src=". $video_file ." type='video/mp4'>";
    echo "</video><br/>";
}

?>
```

or in one loop

```
<?php
$dir    = './videos';
$video_files = [];

foreach(glob($dir.'/*.*') as $file) {
    $file_parts = pathinfo($file);
    if ($file_parts['extension'] == "mp4"){
        echo "<video autoplay>";
        echo "<source src=". $file ." type='video/mp4'>";
        echo "</video><br/>";
    }
}

?>
```